# How to find a 'similarity' measure between 2 pandas dataframes?

Tags: clustering, anomaly-detection

I have 2 pandas dataframes: one big (300.000+ rows) and one little (50- rows) with the **same columns**.
Assuming that the entries of the little one form a cluster I want to identify the entries of the big one that belong to this cluster.

Which algorithm can I use?
Any suggestion is welcome.

I have access to all the python ecosystem and I plan to use this: https://pypi.org/project/gower/.

(I have an approach in mind somehow described here: [scikit-learn one class svm results: how to improve?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/82691/scikit-learn-one-class-svm-results-how-to-improve))

Comment: This is not really clustering if there is only one cluster, clustering would involve selecting the most similar among several clusters. It looks much more like one-class classification. Have you tried running one-class SVM directly on the features instead of going through a distance? This option looks more natural to me.

Comment: I'll try SVM using one hot encoding for categorical variables also.